# SharePoint Like List with GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

All, I would like to create a gridview list with the same behavior as SharePoint's lists.  I want to be able to group items togather and have groups collapesd.

I want to use keep it simple.

I wouldnt mind using the Accordion that comes with jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Bill.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bill Daugherty take a look at Telerik RadGrid :

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx

Comment: I would like to stay away from 3rd party like Telerik.